# multiply login request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I use JMeter to load data using web services. I need to login from JMeter once, then I need to read ids from CSV file and call HTTP request for each id.

My current configuration is as in the attached picture.

[image]

The problem is that in this case login is called for each HTTP Request. I want to change it, so it will be called only once at the beginning. What is the best way to do it in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on login -> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller):

> The Once Only Logic Controller tells JMeter to process the controller(s) inside it only once per Thread, and pass over any requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.
>
> ..
>
> For testing that requires a login, consider placing the login request in this controller since each thread only needs to login once to establish a session.