# Need to login only once per entire run and execute the post login reuests multiple times in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where in I need to login only once per entire duration of the run and execute later requests n number of times. Brief explanation: Threads will be 1000 and duration will be 1 hour. We need to iterate the login request only once per the run (per 1000 users).But post login reuests have to be iterated many times (These requests can be sent to the server only after login). Please help me how can I achieve this in JMeter?

Comment: Doesn't login need to be per thread/user? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902890/multiply-login-request-in-jmeter/46902937#46902937

Answer (score 2):

Put your Login request under [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) (can use right click -> Insert Parent menu).

> The Once Only Logic Controller tells JMeter to process the controller(s) inside it only once per Thread, and pass over any requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.

It'll be executed once per the run (per 1000 users).

Answer (score 1):

Put your "Login Request" under the [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and use the following code in "Condition" area:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && vars.getIteration()==1,)}
```

This way your "Login Request" will be executed only once per 1000 threads/loops.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Execute Sampler Once]

References:

- [__groovy function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
- [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) aka `ctx`
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) aka `vars`
- [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)

Comment: The above code isn't working. Jmeter skipping the requests under if controller and executing later requests. Could you please check the condition?